# Is there any kernel function to convert a physical page to its virtual address?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I get one huge page by `struct page *page=alloc_pages()`, and I want to verify if it is a 2MB page. Is there any kernel function that I can use to convert this page to its virtual address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the pages allocated with `alloc_page()` or the like, you can use `page_address()` to obtain their virtual addresses (see `<linux/mm.h>`).